# Handling webView details in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I am new to the webView concept in Android development, I have used a website url for the webView in my app which works like when you open the app the app will directly show the webView, the website's login page will be the first page that opens up in the webView and then user will be directed to the next page of the website eventually after logging in succesfully, Now I want to save the user's ID and password so that the next time the user opens my app he/she should be taken to the main page of the website in the webView without logging in again and again. Please help me finding the solution for this......

I am not able to figure out how can I save the details or save the response in a webView

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save credentials from a WebView to your app, you can do so by implementing a WebViewClient and intercepting the login form submission.

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        // Find the login form fields and submit button
        val js = """
            var username = document.querySelector('#username');
            var password = document.querySelector('#password');
            var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
            [username.value, password.value];
        """.trimIndent()
        webView.evaluateJavascript(js) { result ->
            // The result is a JSON-encoded array of the username and password
            val credentials = JSONArray(result)
            val username = credentials.getString(0)
            val password = credentials.getString(1)

            // Save the credentials to secure storage (e.g. Android Keystore)
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i make sure the user is signed in the webView, should I use shared preferences or oauth tokens, if you have any tutorial related to it  please share it with me